# Can I use higher capacity batteries in an Online UPS?

Tags: ups, battery

I have a Farber 1KVA Online UPS that uses a pair of 12v, 9AH batteries that are connected in series. the power goes off a lot in my area and the batteries can't keep my PC on more than a minute during heavy use. Can I replace the original batteries with a pair of 12v and a higher amp hour ones?

Answer (score 1):

Three answers:

1. Yes, you can use a higher capacity battery. It will take longer to charge, and I suggest not more than double the capacity. It will give you maybe two minutes.
2. Turn off the computer in an outage and leave the network running. I do this but outages are not frequent.
3. Best suggestion:  Get a bigger UPS. Determine your maximum load and then get a UPS for at least 50% higher capacity than your maximum usage. Size it to give you 15 Minutes at about 80% of maximum load. That is the best thing to do.